# The change in die ulimit on Solaris 10 Sparc Server

Tags: solaris, ulimit

I do want to change ulimit -n to a higher value on an Online-Banking Server, which is very sensible. I can't afford to any kind of disruption on this server. 
I do want to know, can I do these changes without going to risk an interruption in the application and reachability of the server.

Thank you very much in anticipation,

Naeem Sheikh

Answer (score 1):

`ulimit` only affects new processes started from the shell you ran it in (and their children, since limits are inherited from parents).   It will not affect already running applications, so should not disrupt them, but also won't help them if you're trying to change their limits.

Answer (score 0):

I did this type of change to a running Linux server without affecting its functionality. This should be similar to changing it on a Solaris server.